# How do I remove a rows from a dataframe based on column full match and partial match of another column?

Tags: python, dataframe, filtering

I have a dataframe that contains several columns and I want to drop values based on two criterias:
First: Column name should full match my criteria
Second: Column description should partially match another criteria

If both are true, I should remove the row.

Example:
I want to drop every row that contains Blue or Green on the first column and contains "abc" on the second one.

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | abcdefg |
| Red | hrqt |
| Blue | abcde |
| Green | abcd |
| Black | jfg |

Using python v.3.0 or more to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried it out? If yes, please include your code. Thank you

Comment: Both solutions worked, but raibeik solution seems to be more readable / easier to implement.
Thank u all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.drop(((df["Name"]=="Blue") | (df["Name"]=="Green")) & (df["Description"].str.contains("abc")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set two conditions before using `df.loc`.

```
cond1 = df.Name.isin(['Blue','Green'])
cond2 = df.Description.str.contains('abc')

dfd.loc[~(cond1 & cond2)]

    Name Description
1    Red        hrqt
4  Black         jfg
```